# ATtiny10 not running program

Tags: microcontroller, avr, attiny

Im using an arduino uno to upload code via TPI to an Attiny10-TSHR on breadboard.
Communicating with the chip works fine and uploading code but it never runs the code.
By dumping the chip memory I can see that i has uploaded the code fine.

But when I upload some simple code to toggle PB0/PB1/PB2, disconnect MCU and restart nothing happens.
I have tried all GPIO is with oscilloscope and multimeter. I use the same VCC/GND when running the program as when i program it.

It's like its stuck in some programming mode or something. Or the binary im uploading is bogus?

Anyone have any idea? This is the code im compiling with Atmel studio for attiny10.

```
#define F_CPU 12000000UL         /* 12MHz internal oscillator */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
int i;

// PB0 and PB1 outputs
DDRB = (1<<PB0) | (1<<PB1);
// Timer0 in mode 14, fast PWM with ICR0 as top.
// Enable OC0A and OC0B, lower mode bits
TCCR0A = (1<<COM0A1) | (1<<COM0B1) | (1<<WGM01);
// Set top to 1000
ICR0 = 1000;
// Start timer with prescaler 1:8 and set upper mode bits
TCCR0B = (1<<CS01)  | (1<<WGM03) | (1<<WGM02);

while(1)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        OCR0A = i;
        OCR0B = 1000-i;
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
    for (i = 1000; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        OCR0A = i;
        OCR0B = 1000-i;
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}
}
```

It outputs the binary;

```
:100000000AC011C010C00FC00EC00DC00CC00BC084
:100010000AC009C008C011271FBFCFE5D0E0DEBF6E
:10002000CDBF02D039C0ECCF43E041B942EA4EBD6A
:1000300048EE53E053BD42BD4AE14DBD68EE73E06A
:1000400040E050E057BD46BD862F972F841B950B8F
:1000500095BD84BD87EB9BE081509040E9F700C0DF
:1000600000004F5F5F4F493E93E0590759F748EE54
:1000700053E057BD46BD862F972F841B950B95BD2A
:1000800084BD87EB9BE081509040E9F700C0000001
:0C0090004150510B70F7D4CFF894FFCF13
:00000001FF
```

When I read the flash of the chip it returns;

```
**NVM lock**
3F00: FF FF
**configuration**
3F40: FF FF
**calibration**
3F80: 7B FF
**device ID**
3FC0: 1E 90 03 FF

**program**

4000: A0 0C 11 0C 01 0C F0 0C E0 0C D0 0C C0 0C B0 0C
4010: A0 0C 90 0C 80 0C 11 72 F1 FB FC 5E 0D 0E ED FB
4020: DC FB 20 0D 93 0C CE FC 34 0E 14 9B 24 AE E4 DB
4030: 84 EE 35 0E 35 DB 24 DB A4 1E D4 DB 86 EE 37 0E
4040: 04 0E 05 0E 75 DB 64 DB 68 F2 79 F2 48 B1 59 B0
4050: 59 DB 48 DB 78 BE B9 0E 18 05 09 04 9E 7F 00 0C
4060: 00 00 F4 F5 F5 F4 94 E3 39 0E 95 70 95 7F 84 EE
4070: 35 0E 75 DB 64 DB 68 F2 79 F2 48 B1 59 B0 59 DB
4080: 48 DB 78 BE B9 0E 18 05 09 04 9E 7F 00 0C 00 00
4090: 14 05 15 B0 07 7F 4D FC 8F 49 FF FC FF FF FF FF
```

I see that the printed hex from the chip is "inverted" A0 is 0A etc, is that how it's supposed to be presented?

I've spent about 10 hours on this problem now, ANY ideas would be highly appriciated..

Thanks

Comment: How are you programming it? How are you reading back the flash?

Comment: With an Arduino Uno, wired and programmed according to this guide [link](https://junkplusarduino.blogspot.com/p/attiny10-resources.html)

Comment: Does a Blinky program work?

Comment: No it doesnt, all pins are dead regardless of my program. But perhaps its the program itself. I can't see how programming it would work and a blink sketch doesn't if it's hardware related. I have also tried with 3 different chips. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You're either writing the wrong data, or reading the wrong data. Given the software doesn't work, but the signature is correct, I'm going to assume the former. My advice would be to get a proper TPI programmer rather than relying on a random arduino sketch from 8 years ago.

Comment: Do you have a pull up resistor on the reset pin? Something else I would try is verify the mcu is actually running at 12Mhz. Try toggling the pin faster and see if you get it to change. If your clock is running a lot slower than you’re intending it to, it may seem like nothing is happening because a 1ms may be a 1second delay. I’ve had this happen to me before.

Comment: Bunker - Thanks, I've tried just pulling Pin0 high on boot but it's still low. Reset pin is high, also added pullup but still doesnt work. Tom - Thanks I will follow your device and order a proper Atmel Ice programmer. I will update the thread when I solve the problem.

Comment: @Johan personally I've been using cheap USBAsp to program attiny10 without any issues via avrdude. Just FYI.

Comment: @NStorm Ok I just saw this message 1 min after I placed the order for AVR ICE programmer..Well atleast I can use it for ARM stuff as well..Thanks anyways!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. I have tried it now with the Atmel ICE programmer and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but found an updated version of the code you linked to [here](https://github.com/james-tate/Arduino-TPI-Programmer) and it worked great.

Comment: (Note to readers: Although answers that are *only* a link to elsewhere are usually not allowed on Stack Exchange (SE), this answer also gives first-hand knowledge that the original version of the TPI programming software had problems, while the linked version here worked. Also, the  OP [commented above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532315/attiny10-not-running-program/621835#comment1377812_532315) that a different programmer also worked successfully (again indicating that the original version of TPI was the cause). Therefore this is not being treated as a link-only answer.)